# Web Api Parameter binding: snake_case to camelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm doing some work on a new web api project, and my methods/ parameters follow the standard c# naming format; the method name is PascalCase, the parameters are camelCase.

Unfortunately I just discovered that documentation to a client has been published with all the parameters being ruby/ php style, with snake_case type parameter names.

The return objects and POST object were easy to convert; I used a version of [crallen's code](https://gist.github.com/crallen/9238178) to replace the default Json input/ output, but on GET requests, there doesn't seem to be such an easy answer.

I'd prefer to keep my naming conventions the same.  Is there a way to tell the binder to automatically change my_parameter into myParameter for all requests?  Do I have to build a completely different binder?

For example, if I have this as a method signature:

```
[Route("~/api/Widgets")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Widget))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(int widgetId, int groupId)
{
    . . .
```

I would like to be able to use this in the URL

```
https://myserver.com/api/Widgets?widget_id=12345&group_id=54321
```

Do I have to reinvent the wheel to get this to work?  I've seen examples of replacing specific type model binders, but nothing at this level.  Am I better off just changing my parameter names in code?

Comment: try [HttpGet, Route("~/api/Widgets")], tell me if i got the direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a custom `ApiControllerActionSelector` that rewrites `Request.RequestUri` and then calls the base selector.

Here it goes:

First, create the custom selector:

```
public class SnakeCaseActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var newUri = CreateNewUri(
            controllerContext.Request.RequestUri, 
            controllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs());

        controllerContext.Request.RequestUri = newUri;

        return base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
    }

    private Uri CreateNewUri(Uri requestUri, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryPairs)
    {
        var currentQuery = requestUri.Query;
        var newQuery = ConvertQueryToCamelCase(queryPairs);
        return new Uri(requestUri.ToString().Replace(currentQuery, newQuery));
    }

    private static string ConvertQueryToCamelCase(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryPairs)
    {
        queryPairs = queryPairs
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key.ToCamelCase(), x.Value));

        return "?" + queryPairs
            .Select(x => String.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value))
            .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "&" + y);
    }
}
```

Next, create some extensions to convert to camel case and to convert to capitalized words:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToCamelCase(this string source)
    {
        var parts = source
            .Split(new[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return parts
            .First().ToLower() +
            String.Join("", parts.Skip(1).Select(ToCapital));
    }

    public static string ToCapital(this string source)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", char.ToUpper(source[0]), source.Substring(1).ToLower());
    }
}
```

And finally add the action selector to the `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new SnakeCaseActionSelector());
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose an alternative solution using a custom value provider factory:

1. Derive from `QueryStringValueProviderFactory` and override `GetValueProvider`
2. Grab the query string pairs and modify them accordingly.
3. Return an instance of `NameValuePairsValueProvider` taking in the newly modified values.
4. Replace the original `QueryStringValueProviderFactory` in `HttpConfiguration.Services` with your own.

Roughly translates into:

```
public class SnakeQueryStringValueProviderFactory : QueryStringValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider( HttpActionContext actionContext )
    {
        var pairs = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

        // modify query string keys accordingly
        // e.g. remove '_' from query string keys 
        // var newPairs = ...

        return new NameValuePairsValueProvider( newPairs, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    }
}
```

The following should be improved but you get the idea.

```
config.Services.Remove( 
    typeof( ValueProviderFactory ),
    config.Services.GetValueProviderFactories().First( f => f is QueryStringValueProviderFactory ) 
);
config.Services.Insert( typeof( ValueProviderFactory ), 0, new SnakeQueryStringValueProviderFactory() ); // should be first
```

Answer (score 0):

[venerik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502395/venerik), I think your CreateNewUri method could be improved by using the UriBuilder class instead of direct string replacement. This means that you don't have to concatenate the query string with a "?" in your ConvertQueryToCamelCase method. It would resolve the issue when trying to replace a query string in an URL that contains encoded symbols like spaces, colons, percents etc.

```
private Uri CreateNewUri(Uri requestUri, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryPairs)
{
    var currentQuery = requestUri.Query;
    var newQuery = ConvertQueryToCamelCase(queryPairs);
    var builder = new UriBuilder(requestUri) 
    {
        Query = newQuery;
    };
    return builder.Uri;
}

private static string ConvertQueryToCamelCase(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryPairs)
{
    queryPairs = queryPairs
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key.ToCamelCase(), x.Value));

    return queryPairs
        .Select(x => String.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value))
        .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "&" + y);
}
```