# Kebab query string binding in asp.net core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm using asp.net core API with ***TargetFramework net5.0***.

I want to have the Kebab convention in the query string parameters.

I have to declare `[FromQuery(Name = "kebab-convention")]` for each parameter.

Actually, I want to create a custom routing with a kebab Convention.

Do you have any suggestions?
I don't know exactly what should I do?

Thanks,

Comment: 1) Json.NET's [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) is only for **JSON (de)serialization**.  It has no impact on query parameter parsing.  2) [One question per post, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).  This really is a separate question and so I'd suggest breaking it out as such.

Comment: For snake casing of query parameters see [Web Api Parameter binding: snake_case to camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35903448/3744182).  Microsoft also has documentation about customizing of model binding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#globalization-behavior-of-model-binding-route-data-and-query-strings) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: your 2 issues don't seem to be tightly related (each one can be separated into a different question). The first one involves model binding via ***query string***, the second one involves model binding via ***request body***, btw the header you mean (in the second issue) is `content-type` (for specifying the request format sent to the server), `Accept` is for specifying the desired response format returned from the server.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your comment. I'll separate my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a middleware to achieve in single place

```
 public class KebabQueryStringMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public KebabQueryStringMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;

        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Query.Any(q => q.Key.Contains("-")))
            {
                var queryitems = httpContext.Request.Query.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (col, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(col.Key, value)).ToList();
            
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryparameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                foreach (var item in queryitems)
                {
                    var key = KebabToCamelCase(item.Key);
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> newqueryparameter = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, item.Value);
                    queryparameters.Add(newqueryparameter);
                }

                var qb1 = new QueryBuilder(queryparameters);
                httpContext.Request.QueryString = qb1.ToQueryString();
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }

        string KebabToCamelCase(string input) => Regex.Replace(input, "-.", m => m.Value.ToUpper().Substring(1));
    }
```

Then you need to register it in Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
     //Support Kebab Case QueryString
            app.UseMiddleware<KebabQueryStringMiddleware>();
    }
```